# Use localization inside Extension methods in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, resources

I have an application where I have various places from which I throw errors. Out of this, one of the places are my extension methods for various strings and classes.

One of my extension method is below

```
public static string? IsValidPriority(this string? priority)
        {    
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(priority) && new string[] {
                "HIGH",
                "MEDIUM",
                "NORMAL",
                "LOW"
            }.Contains(priority))
            {
                return priority;
            }

            throw new CustomValidationException("Invalid priority");
        }
```

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167350/localization-in-external-class-libraries-in-asp-net-core). and successfully implemented resources for my controllers and normal libraries.

Now, my problem is, I need to use the localized error message inside `CustomValidationException` for all my extensions. Since extensions are `static` methods and are in `static` classes, I cannot DI the `IStringLocalizer` into these methods.

I went through various articles which I could find, and all the articles were telling about how we can add a `localizer` as an `extension`, not how to use it inside a static class.

How can I use `IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>` inside a static class(let's say this above method),
OR
How can I use `IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>` to assign values to a static string variable which can be used inside these error messages?

Comment: There is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235720/asp-net-core-access-istringlocalizer-instance-form-static-class) in SO. Another method before is use `LocalizationHelper` in `Abp.Localization`, But i am not sure it can be used in .Net Core.

Comment: I spent some quality time with the methods mentioned in that issue before posting this question. That work as a static method/extension.. not inside the method to call localized objects